# Get previous year from PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have a sharepoint list Provisions (Year, Cost, Item) and a list of elements, named Contentieux, table Contentieux(Name)

I would like to obtain a PowerBI report that, for a selected (in a slicer by user) year will return a table for the provisions for the respective year as well as for the previous two years:

"Name", "Year-2", "Year-1", "Year"
[image]

I linked the Provision and Contentieux tables, I have already the table that display `Name` and `Year` from the Provisions, now, the problem is to add the column Year-1 and Year-2

Say I have **Items**

```
Id Name
1  Toto
2  Titi
```

and **Provisions**

```
Year Provision ItemId
2019 7         1
2021 4         1
2022 4         1
2023 5         1

2020 10        2
2021 4         2
2022 2         2
2023 1         2
```

The output for the selected year 2022 should be

```
Name  Prov 2020  Prov 2021  Prov 2022
Toto  -          4          4
Titi  10         4          2
```

I tried

```
ProvisionYear-1 = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Provisions[Provision]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(Provisions),
        Provisions[Année] = SELECTEDVALUE(Provisions[Année])-1 &&
        Provisions[ContentieuxId] = EARLIER(Provisions[ContentieuxId])
    )
)
```

The problem is that SELECTEDVALUE(Provisions[Année]) seem to be empty

How to correctly reference the selected value in the select?